How to integrate native iOS navigation (including swipe back) in a Compose Multiplatform project?
I’m working on a Compose Multiplatform project, and I’m looking to implement smooth native iOS navigation specifically for the iOS part of the app, with support for swipe-back gestures (like the standard UINavigationController behavior).
I’ve seen some projects using Voyager for multiplatform navigation, but the user experience isn’t always smooth, especially with navigation gestures like swipe-back, which tend to lack responsiveness.
Is there another recommended approach or best practice to integrate native iOS navigation with gesture support (particularly swipe-back) in a Compose Multiplatform project? Any solutions or tips for achieving smoother navigation on iOS?

if you are using voyager you can loop on your composable screens and wrap them in  UIViewController and use native ios navigation ..... there is more than one tutorial for that ... technically you can do the same with the official  navigation compose but you need to store your composable in list before you add them in the navGraph so you can loop them .... I tried to get them from the navGraph itself to loop but I couldn't . but in voyager you can see the below repo by kashif
https://github.com/Kashif-E/Native-Ios-Navigation-Compose-Multiplatform
